# SilverStripe and PHP libraries - Why don't they get along?

Tags: php, qr-code, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 2.4.7 and am trying to use a PHP library that generates QR codes, see [here](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). Now I thought I'd be ok just adding a folder in the mysite/code folder for the PHP code associated with the QR code generator but when I did SilverStripe had a hissy fit, wouldn't let me build the database and displayed this error:

```
ReflectionException: Class QRCode does not have a constructor
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SilverStripe tries to autoload all classes. This one seems to miss a constructor...

Put the thirdparty code in its own directory and create a file `_manifest_exclude`, so it's not autoloaded. You can then load the class with `require()`, which you normally don't need to do thanks to autoloading ;-)

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up. Fingers crossed I can get it working now.